# Running python command pip -list in command line show Fatal error

Tags: python, command-prompt

When I run command 'pip -list' in command prompt it create fatal error like this:
`Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\python38\python.exe"  "C:\Python38\Scripts\pip.exe" -list': The system cannot find the file specified.`
but when I run command 'python -m pip -list' it work perfectly fine
Can anyone explain what happen and why it happen and how to fix this please here are the pictures of my user environment variable and system environment variable:

1. [user environment variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPmlE.png)
2. [system environment variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSqmx.png)

Comment: sounds like you don't have `pip` in path, but you have `pyhon` in it.

Comment: Did you install python multiple times ?

Comment: Yes, i have tried install python once before then i uninstall it and reinstall it again

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code or error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

try doing this :

```
python -m pip install -U --force pip
```

then close the CMD , open a new one, end then try running again pip list

Comment: it doesnt work, too bad